# How to calculate the size of a vector of this form?

Tags: arrays, matlab, octave

In Matlab, it's easy to define a vector this way:

`x = a:b:c`, where `a`,`b`,`c` are real numbers, `a < c` and `b <= c - a`.

My problem is that I'm having troubles trying to define a formula to calculate the number of elements in `x`.

I know that the problem is solved using the size command, but I need a formula because I'm doing a version of a Matlab program (which uses vectors this way), in another language.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Best regards,

Víctor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a mathematical level you could argue that all of these expressions return the same:

```
size(a:b:c)
size(a/b:c/b)
size(0:c/b-a/b)
```

Now you end up with integers from 0 to that term, which is:

```
floor((c-a)/b+1)
```

There is one problem: Floating point precision. The colon operator does repeated summing, don't know any possibility to predict reproduce that.

Comment: You are right about precision `numel(0:.1:1-eps)==11` but `floor((1-eps-0)/.1+1)==10`